# unity3d draw same objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, similarity

I want to draw many `spheres`.They are all the same but the position.When the number of spheres increase to `10,000`, it become very slow. I would if there is any method to *draw same* things quickly?

I did some experiments to find the problem.

At first I instantiate a simple object with `224 verts` `10,000` times with *dynamic batching*. the result is like this:[image]

Then I add `two faces` to the object and instantiate it `10,000` again. There is no batching but become quicker: [image]

Third time I increase the `verts 100 times` and instantiate it `100` times. It become much quicker:[image]

I wonder where is the different between them. Maybe I should use *static batching* to increase the speed?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called instances. Here is a starting ressource for you:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Depending on what it is that you want to instantiate a thousand times, you can also checkout the concept of a billboard. It is basically a planar object with a fixed texture that will always face the camera no matter from what perspective you look at it. It is mainly used for things that are far away or should not use too much performance (e.g. grass).

Another thing that you need to watch out for is how many times you make draw calls. Try to use draw call batching, when possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to use batching but find some strange result.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include the code/configuration you are using for the results?